# Spring JCache conditional caching

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cache, jcache

Does spring's JCache annotation `@CacheResult` allow conditional caching like Spring's own annotation? e.g.

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames="book", condition="#name.length < 32", unless="#result.hardback")
```

I could not find anything in the documentation nor source code.

Answer (score 3):

First of all there is no "Spring's JCache annotation". And, no, the standard `javax.cache.CacheResult` annotation has no support for conditional caching.

You should basically chose the annotation types you're going to use based on the features that you want to use. You "can" use both in the same project if you want but we strongly recommend not to mix/match them on the same cache.

Answer (score 0):

For those who use `@CacheResult` in Spring and are looking for a simple binary condition to enable caching (eg. `enabled = true/false`), I came up with the following solution:

Suppose you have the following method using `@CacheResult` annotation

```java
@CacheResult(cacheName = "mycachename")
String timeConsumingMethod(String param){
    // time consuming code
    return result;
}
```

you can then define a property in your `.properties` file

```
cache.isenabled=true
```

and use it in the class you used to define the `CacheManager` bean like this:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig {
    @Value("${cache.isenabled}")
    private boolean isCacheEnabled;
    
    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager("mycachename") {
            @Override
            protected Cache createConcurrentMapCache(final String name) {
                if(!isCacheEnabled) return new NoOpCache(name);

                return new ConcurrentMapCache(
                    name,
                    Caffeine.newBuilder()
                        .expireAfterWrite(Duration.ofDays(1))
                        .maximumSize(200).build().asMap(),
                    false
                );
            }
        };
    }
}
```

This way, if `cache.isenabled` is `true`, you return the "real" cache implemented by `ConcurrentMapCache` class, and if `cache.isenabled` is `false` you return an instance of `NoOpCache` that can be used to disable caching, as stated in its [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/support/NoOpCache.html):

> A no operation Cache implementation suitable for disabling caching.